# Atualizar informação pelo HTTP PATCH

Tags: javascript, node.js

Bem, eu quero atualizar a informação `status` pelo `PATCH` mas eu não estou conseguindo, porque eu não sei como funciona, pelo `PUT` e preciso passar todas as informações pelo meu `request.body`, assim eu crio um novo usuário sobre outro, correndo o risco de mudar informações e etc, então estudando os verbos, encontrei o `PATCH`, mas quando eu simplesmente vou lá no **Insomnia**, gero o usuário, pego o id e levo para procurar por `route params`e clico para continuar ele retorna no json assim
`{ "status": "Pronto" }`, mas quando eu utilizo o `GET` para ver se alterou o status ele permance no **Em preparação**. Aonde está o erro e como resolver, obrigado desde já pelo aprendizado...

```
const express = require('express')
const site = express()
const uuid = require('uuid')
site.use(express.json())



const orders = []

site.get('/order', (request, response) => {
    return response.send(orders)
})

site.get('/order/:id', (request, response) => {
    const { id } = request.params
    
    const index = orders.findIndex(user => user.id === id)

    if (index < 0) {
        return response.status(404).json({ error: "user not found" })

    }

    return response.json(orders[index])
})

site.post('/order', (request, response) => {
    const { clientName, price, status, order } = request.body

    const orderPerson = ({ id: uuid.v4(), order, clientName, price, status })

    orders.push(orderPerson)

    console.log(orderPerson)

    return response.status(201).json(orderPerson)
})

site.put('/order/:id', (request, response) => {

    const {clientName, price, status, order} = request.body
    const { id } = request.params

    const updateOrders = ({id, order, clientName, price, status})

    const index = orders.findIndex(user => user.id === id)

    if (index < 0) {
        return response.status(404).json({ error: "user not found" })

    }

    orders[index] = updateOrders
    return response.json(updateOrders)
})

site.delete('/order/:id', (request, response) => {
    const { id } = request.params
    
    const index = orders.findIndex(user => user.id === id)

    if (index < 0) {
        return response.status(404).json({ error: "user not found" })

    }

    orders.splice(index, 1)

    return response.status(204).json(orders)
})

site.patch('/order/:id', (request, response) => {
    const { id } = request.params
    const {clientName, price, status, order} = request.body
    const updateStatus = ({id, order, clientName, price, status: "Pronto"})
    
    const index = orders.findIndex(user => user.id === id)

    if (index < 0) {
        return response.status(404).json({ error: "user not found" })

    }

    console.log(request)
    return response.json(updateStatus)
})

port = 3001
site.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`server starded in port ${port}`)
})
```

Comment: Ficou faltando fazer o update no array. Ex.:    `orders[index] = updateStatus`

Comment: o put e path são bem parecidos, faltou essa linha para atualizar a array orders mesmo. para o patch seria bom fazer uma lógica para atualizar só os itens que estão sendo enviados pelo body, pois nele podemos enviar uma única propriedade.

Comment: Mas é isso, eu quero atualizar os itens enviado do pelo body

Answer (score -1):

Observe que seu método PATCH não está atualizando a sua "base de dados" (array de orders). Você está apenas enviando um objeto estático de volta para o client-side.

Para que o seu serviço funcione como o esperado, será necessário atualizar a base de dados e, então, retornar a resposta do registro atualizado, assim:

```
site.patch('/order/:id', (request, response) => {
  const { id } = request.params
  const {clientName, price, status, order} = request.body
  const updateStatus = ({id, order, clientName, price, status: "Pronto"})

  const index = orders.findIndex(user => user.id === id)

  if (index < 0) {
    return response.status(404).json({ error: "user not found" })
  }

  console.log(request)
  // CORREÇÃO AQUI
  orders[index] = updateStatus
  return response.json(updateStatus)
})
```